# Autohotkey - How can Blockinput, MouseMove block the curson move from my wacom (tablet) stylus

Tags: autohotkey, tablet, stylus

I have an AHK script that moves a panel from ArtRage, I use `blockinput, mousemove` before doing the click and drag, so the mouse can't move the cursor while AHK is doing the click and drag, but since I use this script in ArtRage, my tablet can interfere with the click and drag despite I used `blockinput, mousemove`, hence the panel I wanted to drag end up in another different position. Is there a way to temporarily block the input from my wacom tablet? so the position of the stylues could no't interfere with my AHK script?

Can the AHKHID help me on this issue, I saw that it is very complex code. Does anybody have some knowledge on this issue?

Comment: You are clicking and dragging programmatically vs. using `WinMove`?

Comment: yes cuz it is not a window, is more a panel inside the artrage window and there like 8 panels with the same class name inside

Answer (score 0):

Use `WinGet,List` to get a list of all the panel windows with the matching class identifier.

Loop through the list. There is example code in the help files that basically does this already, just use the appropriate WinTitle for searching with the desired `ahk_class` identifier.

Inside the loop, use `WinGetPos` to get the size and position of each window.

Do a comparison of each window position against where you know the window is located... i.e., where you would click if you were going to click it for dragging.

Once you find the matching window, you can break the loop and use that window as an argument to `WinMove` to move the window programmatically.

This isn't a direct answer to the question (as asked) but it's going to be more reliable, faster, and less clunky, even if you do figure out how to block the stylus input.

Comment: inside ArtRage all windows are called ToolWindow, so I guess I can't select one cuz all are called the same

Comment: You would need to use the window ID, after looping through the id list returned by `WinGet, List` to determine which one you want to move

Comment: Hi JJohnston2 I searched in AHK help `WinGet` https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGet.htm which is the example you are refering to? could you please post an example of How I whould loop through all windows inside ahk_class XXX? thanks advanced.

Comment: Search for "list".  Example #2.  To use the example code replace the WinGet list arguments for WinTitle etc. to match your WinTitle, i.e., ahk_class XXX